# How to dragover in this algorithm using d3.js drag.behaviour()?

Tags: d3.js, drag, self

I am trying to design an association miminap using d3.js. My goal is to position different items according to data and associate them using a drag function.

I try to calculate distance to different elements and if distance is lower than total radius, I consider this condition as a dragover. However drag function keeps selecting the node I drag instead of the node I drag it to.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
.on('dragstart', function() {})
.on('drag', function(d) {
nodes=d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll("circle")[0];
nodes.pop(this);

var minDist=1000;
for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
    var currentNode=d3.select(nodes[i]);
    var r1=parseInt(this.style.r);
    var r2=parseInt(currentNode.style("r"));
    var dx=d3.event.x-parseInt(currentNode.style("cx"));
    var dy=d3.event.y-parseInt(currentNode.style("cy"));
    var dist=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

    if(dist<(r1+r2)) {
        d.con=currentNode.attr("id");
        currentNode.style("fill","red");
        console.log(currentNode[0][0]);
    }


}

d3.select(this)
    .style("cx",d3.event.x)
    .style("cy",d3.event.y);

})
```

Why does my futile attempt to remove the node I drag by entering `nodes.pop(this)` does not work ?

I have added an editable codepen version : 
https://codepen.io/TeaCult/pen/ezJVyz?editors=1111

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you replicate this via codepen?

Comment: This is my first codepen, I hope it works.
https://codepen.io/TeaCult/pen/ezJVyz?editors=1111